# BigCommerce - Is there a way to write data to a database from store and then retrieve it and display it on Front End?

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm not sure if this is possible.

I'm looking to create a Question and Answer widget for a BigCommerce store. The idea is the user will type in a question on the product page, the question will get added to a MySQL database on a different server. The store owner would then access an edit page on the other server and either reply and post, reply or delete the question. If the store owner decides to reply and post, the question and answer would then be displayed on the original product page.

The part that I'm not sure how to do is the last part: displaying the question and answer on the original product page.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to pull it in via the Bigcommerce platform itself, but why not pull the content in with javascript? It's not ideal, but you should be able to get that to work.